# How to batch up Postgres files

Tags: postgresql

I have a number of files which need to be run against a postgres database. They are stored as separate files for reasons of maintenance and configuration management.  I am using this type of method to run them

```
acro =# \i ./psql.sql   
acro =# \i ./psql.function1.sql
acro =# \i ./psql.function2.sql
acro =# \i ./psql.function3.sql
acro =# \i ./psql.function4.sql
```

etc

Is there a way to batch these commands or these file names up, so that they can be run as a single interactive command ?

Thanks

Comment: `cat psql.sql psql.function1.sql psql.function2.sql | psql`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a file `batch.sql` that looks like this:

```
\i ./psql.sql   
\i ./psql.function1.sql
\i ./psql.function2.sql
\i ./psql.function3.sql
\i ./psql.function4.sql
```

and run it with `psql -f batch.sql`.

Comment: this file would need to be edited everytime a new file is added or removed.

Comment: Loop thorugh files in a directory. Something like : for f in *; do \i ./psql $f; done

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.